# ADOTemplate query with idbparameter and like expression

Tags: c#, spring.net

I have a DAO that queries the database using spring.net and ADOTemplate:

```
var sql = "select id, name, description from item where description like '%@description%'";
var dbParameters = AdoTemplate.CreateDbParameters();
dbParameters.Add("description", DbType.String).Value = query.Description;
return AdoTemplate.QueryWithRowMapperDelegate<Item>(...)
```

This fails, as the sql string is sent literally to the database without dbparameter expansion.

My solution to this is the following

```
var sql = "select id, name, description from item where description like '%" + query.Description + "%'";
return AdoTemplate.QueryWithRowMapperDelegate<Item>(...)
```

but I would really like to use IDBParameters as the current solution opens up for sql injection attacks.  I Can't find anything in the documentation on how to achieve this.